# Parallel releases after built in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am running into problems getting my build servers to run releases in parallel.

I just recently created my second build and test server.  Both servers correctly run builds in parallel.  And each of my builds triggers a release upon successful completion.  However, only one server at a time will run a release.

I have verified that both servers are configured correctly because if I take down one server the other one starts running the releases correctly.  However, when both are stood up together only one of them will run releases.

Is there a setting in TFS that does not allow multiple separate release definitions to run in parallel on different machines?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I am using TFS 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TFS concurrent pipeline gives you the ability to **run a single release at a time in a team project collection.**

You can keep hundreds or even thousands of release definitions in your collection. But, **to run more than one release at a time, you need additional concurrent pipelines.**

> One free concurrent pipeline is included with every collection in a
>   Team Foundation server. Every **Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber**
>   in a Team Foundation server contributes one additional concurrent
>   pipeline. You can buy additional private pipelines from the Visual
>   Studio Marketplace.

Purchase additional concurrent pipelines

If you need to run more concurrent releases, you can buy [additional private pipelines from the Visual Studio marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-private-pipelines). Since there is no way to directly purchase concurrent pipelines from Marketplace for a TFS instance at present, you must first buy concurrent pipelines for a VSTS account. After you buy the private pipelines for a VSTS account, you enter the number of purchased concurrent pipelines manually on the resource limits page described below.

```
http://{your_server}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_buildQueue?_a=resourceLimits
```

---

*Note: above is for TFS2017/2018.*

If you are using TFS2015, take a look at this question: [*Do I need concurrent pipelines to use release management in versions before TFS 2017?*](http://Do%20I%20need%20concurrent%20pipelines%20to%20use%20release%20management%20in%20versions%20before%20TFS%202017?)

More details suggest you go through the official link in MSDN: **[Concurrent release pipelines in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/licensing/concurrent-pipelines-tfs?view=vsts#tfs_before_2017)**

Answer (score 0):

The system seems to still be based on the honor code.

Through the link PatrickLu-MSFT gave I was able to change the number to anything I wanted, even though I did not actually purchase any additional licenses.

After resetting the additional licenses back to zero, I also found this link:

```
http://{your_server}:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses
```

Again, it seemed to be based on the honor code here as well because I was able to add users with subscriptions to less than Enterprise to the VS Enterprise group.

However, when all my exploring was done, I was able to use that final link to enter the people who do have Enterprise subscriptions and that changed my overall license count so I was able to run releases in parallel.